# Vector Geometry: Ratios of Subdivided Lengths in a Parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors

> Suppose that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.  Let point $E$ be the point on segment $CD$ that divides it in the ratio $CE:ED=3:4$.  Let $Q$ be the point of intersection of $BD$ and $AE$.  I want to show that $Q$ divides $BD$ in the ratio $BQ:QD=7:4$.
>
> [image: http://i61.tinypic.com/b4byp2.jpg]

Here's what I have done so far:

I have defined a vector for each side:

$$\vec{u}=\vec{AD}=\vec{BC}$$

$$\vec{v}=\vec{BA}=\vec{CD}$$

so that gives me these other relations:

$$\vec{CE}=\frac{3}{7}\vec{v}$$

$$\vec{ED}=\frac{4}{7}\vec{v}$$

$$\vec{BQ}=t(\vec{v}+\vec{u})$$ where $t$ is any (non-zero) real number;

$$\vec{QD}=k(\vec{v}+\vec{u})$$ where $k$ is any (non-zero) real number.

The proof would be complete if I could show that $\frac{k}{t} = \frac{4}{7}$.

So far I only know that $k+t=1$.

Could you give me some insight as to how to use vectors to complete this geometric proof?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. You already have $\vec{BQ}=t(\vec{v}+\vec{u})$. There is another way to get $\vec{BQ}$, namely $\vec{BQ}=\vec{BA} + r\vec{AE}$ where $r$ is between $0$ and $1$. By your work above, $\vec{BA}=\vec v$, and $\vec{AE} = \vec{AD} - \vec{ED} = \vec{u} -\frac47\vec{v}$. This gives two equations for the same object $\vec{BQ}$, expressed in terms of $\vec u$ and $\vec v$:
$$\begin{align}\vec{BQ}&=t(\vec v + \vec u)=t\vec v + t\vec u\\
\vec{BQ}&=\vec v + r(\vec u -\frac47\vec v)=(1-\frac47r)\vec v + r\vec u
\end{align}$$
The corresponding coefficients on $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ must be equal in these two expressions:
$$
\begin{align}
t&=1-\frac47r\\
t&=r
\end{align}$$
Now solve these two equations for $r$ and $t$, and use your equation $k+t=1$ to get $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try. We have $$\vec{BD} = \vec{BA} + \vec{AD} = \vec{v} + \vec{u}.$$

Then we have $$\vec{QD} = k\vec{BD} = k(\vec{v} + \vec{u})$$

Note that $$\vec{QE} = k\vec{AQ} = k(\vec{AD} + \vec{DE}) = k(\vec{u} - \frac{4}{7}\vec{v}).$$

Moreover, one has $$k(\vec{v} + \vec{u}) = \vec{QD} = \vec{QE} + \vec{ED} = k(\vec{u} - \frac{4}{7}\vec{v}) + \frac{4}{7}\vec{v}.$$

One then gets $k=\frac{4}{11}$.